# Access Java local variable via Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

Through Groovy script (meta programming), I can access and modify the variables which are declared in globally in a java class. Even I can invoke or override a java method using the script. But I can not find any way to access the variables which are inside a particular method of class.

Consider a class MethodInjection.java

```
public class MethodInjection {

static String text = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Execute();        
}

public static void Execute() throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Before Value : "+text);        
    String script = loadScript("Path_to_script");
    Script scripting = new GroovyShell().parse(script);
    scripting.run();
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("After Value : "+text); 
}

public static void access()
{
    String local ="";
}

static String loadScript(String fileName) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        br.close();
    }
}}
```

And the same Script is :

```
import methodinjection.MethodInjection

def access = new MethodInjection()
access.text = "Modified"
access.metaClass.access.local = "change"
access.print()
println access.metaClass.access.local
```

and I got output as

```
Before Value : 
After Value : Modified
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass$ExpandoMetaProperty@75f9ecc
```

But I need to modify local variable and print it through Groovy script.

Tried many ways but could not found any

Comment: what makes you think this is/should be possible?

Comment: You can use a Java bytecode manipulation library. In any case all this doesn't look like a good idea, why are you doing all this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Groovy cannot do that.

Longer answer: In the end Groovy depends on what the JVM and Reflection do offer. It was actually on purpose to not include features, which require the transformation of the bytecode for "normal" Groovy logic like meta programming. Local variables exists only as "slots" that may have a name in the methods bytecode. Thus you would need a bytecode manipulation library as was mentioned here already.